# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have tried to add more fields to the laravel authentication but when I run a registry I get this error:

**"Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\voluntariosdama\ ▶"**

This is the code of RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'dni' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'apellidos' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'telefono' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'dni' => $data['dni'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'apellidos' => $data['apellidos'],
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="dni" class="col-md-4 control-label">DNI</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="dni" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('dni') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="apellidos" class="col-md-4 control-label">Apellidos</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="apellidos" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('apellidos') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 control-label">Telefono</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="telefono" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

What can happen?

Comment: You are passing a string to a function that should be an array. Can't help you more than that as you haven't given us the function that is actually giving you the error.

Comment: Try `Log::info($data);` before you create the user, then check your log file. By the way, you have an issue with your form where multiple inputs are named `name`, so not all of the data may be passing in right.

Comment: Where can I put this? Log :: info ($ data);
I do not see that it has several fields with the name "name"

Comment: Place it in your create function, right before `return User::create([`. As for the name fields, look at `ini`, `apellidos`, and `telefono`. The `id` on the input does not get passed into the post data, only the name and value attributes.